# hashcode implementation based on the Object Class

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

hi guys i have a little problem here to solve.

I have created an equals() method which is only based on the class of the object so that if two obj are of the same class the obj1.equals(obj2) return true.
now my question is, How do i implement a hashcode() based only on the obj Class ??

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj.getClass() == this.getClass()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return 79658765;` (for example: any integer would do). Why are you doing that? That seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: You can return hashcode of full class name. But Why you are writing such terrible equals method ? Please elaborate more.

Comment: What's the use case for this? It seems like something that will blow up in your face...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the `hashCode` of the `Class` instance:

```
public int hashCode ()
{
    return getClass().hashCode();
}
```

This would ensure that two objects which are equal based on your `equals()` implementation would have the same `hashCode()`.